# Linux IP aliasing: how to setup Apache listen IP to be source IP for the same destination

Tags: linux, apache, networking

I am using the IP aliasing in my `CentOS 5 x86_64`. To make this example simple: IP address `A` is the `eth0` address, IP address `B`  is the `eth0:0`  address. I have 2 Apache instances(version 2.2.3), each one is listening on an different IP address - 1st Apache instance is listening on `A` IP address, 2nd instance is listening on `B`  IP address. If Apache `B` would like to make a call to some external services outside the server the request always get out with the `A` source IP (primary IP address of the interface).

The question is: Can I force Apache to makes the request with `B`'s IP as a source? Please keep in mind that a destination address of the request is always the same for both Apaches. I know that for different destination I can use "ip rules" to make it works.

Thanks in advance,
Michal.

Comment: Could you provide an example when Apache itself will make external requests?

Comment: I havent' tried anything yet. Regarding the external request made by Apache: Apache is having OAM (Oracle Access Manager) module loaded and the module is checking if the user has been authenticated or authorized to go the the resource he is trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

You could use iptables with `-m owner --uid-owner ...` if you make those two instances of Apache run under different `uid` values (see `iptables-extensions(8)` or `iptables(8)`), and the MARK target to distinguish the packets and then check the mark with your ip rules. That's a universal way that doesn't require support in the application itself.

Of course the application could `bind(3p)` to the local address if such a configuration was supported.